Rendering Clips on GPU
I used Blender 4.2 to cut a few clips together but I can't get Blender to render on the GPU. I set CUDA as the Render Device and GPU as device in the scene properties as seen here:


However this doesn't change the rendering speed and the CPU keeps on being at about 70% usage from Blender.

This setting is just for the (post processing) compositing, that's why it says "Compositor". For rendering the image this does not change anything at all. Only when using Cycles you can switch between rendering with CPU or GPU. And believe me, there you will notice a speed difference.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60798/19307

Aslo you have an RTX graphics card, you would better use it with Optix instead of Cuda.

Blender's video editor does not make use of the GPU; it sadly only uses the CPU.However, the compositor just updated in 4.2 to fully use the GPU.So, you could try doing all your video editing in the composite, to make use of the GPU, but that would probably be more trouble than it's worth.

It would only do the composition processing on the GPU. The file encoding would still be determined by the output codec, which Blender only have CPU-powered ones. And whatever you can do in the VSE is so simple, I doubt you can gain any significant computing time by doing it in the compositor instead.

Ah good point, I didn't think of that.
